# Ansible - List comparison issue while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'

Tags: ios, ansible, cisco

I am writing an audit playbook that compares the running config against the golden config. Does Ansible allow you to compare a vars list against the stdout_lines list?

```yaml
---
- name: Logging
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no
  vars: 
    golden: ["logging userinfo","logging buffered 65536"]
   - name: Grab Logging Config
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        commands:
          - show run | i logging
      register: logging_config
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: logging_config.stdout_lines
    
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Items on switch but not in Standard {{ golden | difference({{ logging_config.stdout_lines }}) }}"
```

I get the following error message:

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


fatal: [atl01-sw-lab01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: Items on switch but not in Standard {{ golden | difference({{ logging_config.stdout_lines }}) }}. expected token ':', got '}'"}
```

This is the output of logging_config_stdout_lines:

```yaml
"logging_config.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "no logging buffered",
            "no logging reload",
            "no logging console",
            "no device-tracking logging theft"
        ]
```

I am expecting a list with the difference.

Comment: According your use case (description) "_compares the running config against the golden config_", wouldn't be the module [`ios_config`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_config_module.html) and the [`Example`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_config_module.html#examples) about "_Check the running-config against master config_" the right task?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of *msg* is wrong. The curly braces can't be nested

```yaml
  {{ golden | difference({{ logging_config.stdout_lines }}) }}
```

The correct syntax is

```yaml
  {{ golden | difference( logging_config.stdout_lines) }}
```

Given the below data for testing

```yaml
  logging_config:
    stdout_lines:
      - ["no logging buffered",
         "no logging reload",
         "no logging console",
         "no device-tracking logging theft"]
      - ["stdout line1 of cmd 2",
         "stdout line2 of cmd 2",
         "stdout line3 of cmd 2"]

  golden:
    - ["no logging buffered",
       "no logging reload",
       "no logging console",
       "no device-tracking logging theft"]
    - ["stdout line1 of cmd 2"]
```

Declare the variable to get "*items on the switch but not in standard*"

```yaml
  golden_diff: "{{ logging_config.stdout_lines|difference(golden) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  golden_diff:
  - - stdout line1 of cmd 2
    - stdout line2 of cmd 2
    - stdout line3 of cmd 2
```

There are two problems. From this list, you can't tell which command differs and what are the details of the difference. To solve this, compare the items in the lists. Declare the variables

```yaml
  golden_diff_str: |
    {% for i,j in logging_config.stdout_lines|zip(golden) %}
    - {{ i|difference(j) }}
    {% endfor %}
  golden_diff: "{{ golden_diff_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  golden_diff:
  - []
  - - stdout line2 of cmd 2
    - stdout line3 of cmd 2
```

This looks better. You can see that there are no differences in the first command. In the second command, there are two lines not in standard.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    logging_config:
      stdout_lines:
        - ["no logging buffered",
           "no logging reload",
           "no logging console",
           "no device-tracking logging theft"]
        - ["stdout line1 of cmd 2",
           "stdout line2 of cmd 2",
           "stdout line3 of cmd 2"]

    golden:
      - ["no logging buffered",
         "no logging reload",
         "no logging console",
         "no device-tracking logging theft"]
      - ["stdout line1 of cmd 2"]

    golden_diff_str: |
      {% for i,j in logging_config.stdout_lines|zip(golden) %}
      - {{ i|difference(j) }}
      {% endfor %}
    golden_diff: "{{ golden_diff_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: golden_diff
      vars:
        golden_diff: "{{ logging_config.stdout_lines|difference(golden) }}"

    - debug:
        var: golden_diff
    - debug:
        msg: |
          Items on switch but not in Standard:
          {{ golden_diff|to_nice_yaml }}
```